# SyntaxError: missing } after property list jquery

Tags: jquery

My jQuery code was working fine before. But now it is giving error **SyntaxError: missing } after property list jquery**

I have seen so many questions on SO and checked my code so many times but unnable to find error so please help me to find error in following code.

```
         $("#savedata").click(function () {
     var var1 = $('#email').val();
     var var2 = $('#password').val();
     var var3 = $('#name').val();
     var var4 = $('#organization').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "savedata",
         data: {
             var1: var1,
             var2: var2,
             var3: var3,
             var4: var4
         },
         success: function (resp) {
             alert('Registration Successful');
         }
     });

     return false;
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you have a lot of typo.

The right syntax is :

```
 $("#savedata").click(function () {
     var var1 = $('#email').val();
     var var2 = $('#password').val();
     var var3 = $('#name').val();
     var var4 = $('#organization').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "savedata",
         data: {
             var1: var1,
             var2: var2,
             var3: var3,
             var4: var4
         },
         success: function (resp) {
             alert('Registration Successful');
         }
     });

     return false;
 });
```

Comment: In order to complete the @sdespont's answer, you can simply use the http://jshint.com/ to find your JavaScript code problems.

Comment: thnx @sdespont it works :)